# Authentication from scratch - How safe are the cookies from being tampered with?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, omniauth

Am attempting to do authentication from scratch, using Omniauth.

I followed Ryan Bate's [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth). But before I roll out an implementation, I'd like to understand a few things.

In his screencast, he has a `helper_method` in the `application_controller`:

```
helper_method :current_user

private

def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end
```

Code above, checks for `user_id`.

I know [sessions are encrypted](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html) (and stored in cookies). However, they are readable, but cannot be modified. How hard would it be for someone to hijack a session with a fake `user_id`? What's stopping anyone from creating a cookie from scratch or via some "cookie injector" method (if such a thing exists).

Am trying to understand how these cookies are protected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sessions are generally kept server-side, and the only thing passed to/from the client via cookies is the session identifier. Storing actual session data in that cookie would be a major security hole, regardless of how well it's encrypted. e.g. if you were cheap and used rot-13 "encryption", it'd be trivial for a user to do fiddle the data and set `superuser=1`.

But with the session ID, that's impossible - there's nothing in the cookie that could be used to fiddle with the server-side data. At best they could send back random session ID values, and try to hijack someone else's session. With a sufficiently large ID hash, the chances of finding another session to hijack are vanishingly small.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. So when a session is created, it is associated with a session identifier, which is stored server-side. The session identifier is used to validate whether a session is real. But what if one were to create a fake cookie with the exact session identifier and fake user_id. Wouldn't that validate through?

Comment: Except that this is not how Rails behave by default. You need to switch to ActiveRecord session store to get this behavior.

Comment: a typical session cookie is basically just `nameOfSession=long_ugly_alphanumeric_string`. There's no username/password/whatever data in there. JUST that string, which is used to tell the server which session file/db record/whatever to load when a session is activated. That's where the whole "guessing" business comes in. if the hash length is short/simple enough (e.g. a simple incrementing integer) then you can hijack a session by simply changing the session cookie to someone else's session ID. but if the hash is complicated enough, that's highly unlikely.

Comment: You said "Storing actual session data in that cookie would be a major security hole". Isn't that what `session[:user_id] = user.id` is doing?

Comment: Or does the actual value get stored server-side?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session explains it all. For CookieStore, all data is stored on the client. "The cookie data is cryptographically signed to make it tamper-proof, but it is not encrypted, so anyone with access to it can read its contents but not edit it (Rails will not accept it if it has been edited)."

Answer (score 1):

The link you provided gives the best answers, I think. And covers a lot of far more insidious attacks that I'd be more concerned about for sensitive applications.

In Rails it would be very difficult to submit a forged or fiddled cookie that contained session data because the cookies are signed by the server and the submitted cookie is checked to make sure the signature is correct. Changing cookie values would require knowing the secret key the server signs cookies with.

The best practice is to only store very small bits (preferably IDs) in the session anyway, and if you are concerned about someone being able to create a session cookie containing user id from scratch, the easy answer is: don't put the user.id in the cookie. Instead generate a GUID for each user that serves as the id in the cookie. This way you can expose user.id in URLs without fear that knowing some user's id will allow an attacker to forge a cookie that will be of use.